# User Input For List of Floats Not Repeating

Tags: python

So I'm writing some code for my class and have to have a list of floats that are input by a user and print them out with normal iteration and reverse iteration, and I have basically all of it done. But when it should ask multiple times for the user input, it only asks one time then prints everything out and finishes without asking multiple times. 
Any help would be appreciated as to why it isnt asking multiple times for input even though I have a for loop?
Is there an easier way to get a list of floats from user input that I don't know about?
Thanks

```
    emptyList = []
    userInput = high = low = total = float(input("Input a float > "))
    emptyList.append(userInput)

    for y in range(len(emptyList)-1):
        userInput = float(input("Input a float > "))
        emptyList.append(userInput)
        total += emptyList
        if userInput > high:
            high = userInput
        if userInput < low:
            low = userInput

    avg = total / len(emptyList)
    above_avg = below_avg = 0

    for y in range(len(emptyList)):
        if emptyList[y] > avg:
            above_avg += 1
        if emptyList[y] < avg:
            below_avg += 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your logic and according to that you are running your first for loop to the length of **emptyList-1** so, after adding one element your emptylist's length becomes 1 and 1-1=0 so, your for loop will work only to 0th index and after that it will break.
I tried this

```
a=[]
b = []
t=0
count = 0
total = 0
for i in range(0,5):
    x= float(input())
    count = count + 1
    total = total+ x
    a.append(x)
print(count)
for i in range(count-1,-1,-1):
    print('Aya')
    print (i)
    b.append(a[i])
for i in range(0,count-1):
    for j in range(i,count):
        if(a[i]>a[j]):
            t=a[i]
            a[i]=a[j]
            a[j]=t


print(a)
print(b)
print(total)
print(total/count)
print(a[0])
```

and found it working perfectly fine for me and my for loop is taking values on every iteration.

Comment: Hi, yeah this worked for me as well! I have to also get the total, average, lowest and highest number of the inputs as well, but my low and total arent showing the right number, where can I paste my source code to see if you can help me see why?

Comment: Yes I know those built in functions would work, but part of the assignment is we cant use the built in functions and have to do it with code. How would I go about getting those numbers then?

Comment: you can do one more thing you can sort the list in ascending order and get the first and last elements for min and max respectively. for total just traverse the list and keep on adding number to total like total = total + ith element and for average just divide this total with the length of list by counting the length while traversing.

Comment: I have updated the code and I think this would work for you

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This did end up working for me! 1 more thing though is I have to print the numbers in reverse order, and to do that I did: `print("The numbers you input in reverse order is: ")for numbers in emptyList[::-1]:
    print(numbers)` but this printed each number out on a new line, how can I make it print to one single line of code?

Comment: I have added the feature to print numbers in reverse order also.

Comment: Thanks again! This was a real help.

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this:

```
n = int(input("Number of inputs: "))

emptyList = []
while n:
        userInput = float(input("Enter a Float > "))
        emptyList.append(userInput)
        n-=1

print(emptyList)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This does work, but part of the assignment is getting the total number input along with the high and low values etc. How could I incorporate those into this version of the input?